# Brackets are in the label

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

I made a little script in Python with `tkinter` and when I want to change the label with the results of the script, brackets are shown on each part of the results, between string variable and float.

```py
# tant que v n'est pas égale aux nombre de valeurs
# dans la liste le programme se répète
while v < len(portail_x):
    #  calcule de distance entre deux points avec la formule
    # \sqrt{(x_{b}-x_{a})²+(y_{b}-y_{a})²}=\overrightarrow{AB}
    p1 = sqrt((xj - portail_x[v]) ** 2 + (yj - portail_y[v]) ** 2)

    v = v + 1

    # les distances sont misent dans une nouvelle liste
    portail_total_distance.append(p1)

# définition d'une nouvelle liste
nouv_portail_total_distance = portail_total_distance[:]

# classement des valeurs de la nouvelle liste
# dans l'ordre croissant
nouv_portail_total_distance.sort(reverse=False)

# définition de l'indice pour trouver la plus petite distance dans la liste triée
coor = portail_total_distance.index(nouv_portail_total_distance[0])

# affichage de la réponse
phrase_rep1.set((
    'Le portail le plus proche de toi est à',
    nouv_portail_total_distance[0],
    'blocks de ta position'
))

# affichage de la réponse
phrase_rep2.set((
    'Le portail se trouve aux coodonnée X',
    portail_x[coor],
    'et y',
    portail_y[coor]
))
```

And the result is this: brackets `{}` are in the text on the window and I don't know how to remove them:

[image]

Comment: try using `.set(... + ... + ...)` instead of `.set((...))`. Make sure to convert everything to strings first.

Comment: better yet, use string formatting, such as an f-string.

Comment: See comment in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179246/selected-item-from-treeview-tkinter-in-python-returns-curly-brackets#comment120502245_68179246).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the value of the label to a single string expression. Either compose it beforehand or do it right in the `.set()` call:

```
# affichage de la réponse
phrase_rep1.set(f'Le portail le plus proche de toi est à {nouv_portail_total_distance[0]} blocks de ta position')

# affichage de la réponse
phrase_rep2.set(f'Le portail se trouve aux coodonnée X {portail_x[coor]} et y {portail_y[coor]}')
```